# SDN - ofsofswitch13 packet handling

Tags: openflow, mininet, sdn

I'm trying to change an existing cpqd switch to make it act as a statefull firewall that can define flow entries that look at the TCP headers flags.

The open source project that I'm using is:
 https://github.com/CPqD/ofsoftswitch13

I'm having problems understanding where the changes in the code must happen, or in other words where does the switch listens and monitors traffic of packets between hosts. I'm not sure how to debug this so I'm currently using prints in the code.
Any suggestions about how to find the places where a packet is sent or recieved in the code?
or about how to debug the code easily ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an application which uses Openflow to setup flow tables from switches.
This library abstracts Openflow protocol, which is the protocol that knows how to interact with Openflow-enabled switches.

If you want implement a firewall, you must write an application that will use this library to write entries in the flows tables. You will need to have a network infrastructure with switches (you could simulate it with Mininet)

As the example suggests (refers to topic: Install a flow to match IPv6 packets), you could simplify this examples to create a flow entry to bock some flow. You just need to create a Match with no action (which means it will block flows).

I would recommend you to take a look at this tutorial: http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/opendaylight/. It' simple and straightforward. If you would like interact with switches by REST, take a look at it: http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=68.